# Build land classes from GIS data

Tags: python, land-classification, aggregation, geodataframe

I have combined geo-referenced terrain, climate, and soil data with the requirements of the different agricultural food crops in order to build land classes that tell you where which crop can be grown.
These are the crops of my investigation:

```
crops = ["wheat", "rye", "barley", "oat", "triticale", "corn", "corn silage",
         "rice", "potato", "sugarbeet", "cabbage", "brussels sprout",
         "cauliflower", "carrot", "celery", "leek", "spinach", "asparagus",
          "lettuce", "other salad", "onion", "tomato", "cucumber", "pumpkin",
          "bell pepper", "zucchini", "soy", "pea", "green bean", "chickpea",
          "lupinus", "sunflower", "rapeseed", "apple", "pear", "cherry",
          "plum", "apricot", "peach", "currant, black- and raspberry",
          "strawberry", "blue- and elderberry", "grape", "walnut", "hazlenut",
         ]
```

After processing the different layer shapefiles, I used  `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Union` in QGIS to combine the layers. I processed the shapefile for the crop requirements by checking the requirements of each polygon in a GeoDataFrame in Python.

[image]

You can see the dataframe in the screenshot above. The structure looks like this:

```
      wheat             rye             barley    ...            hazlenut   area   geometry
0     True              True            True                     False             789    POLYGON((...
1     True              True            True                     False             3321   POLYGON((...
2     True              True            True                     False             5200   POLYGON((...
3     True              True            True                     True              1391   POLYGON((...
4     True              True            False                    False             3029   POLYGON((...
5     True              True            False                    False             13321  POLYGON((...
.............................................................................................
98766 True              False           False                    True              24     POLYGON((...
```

Thereby, the dots `...` should indicate the other crops and other polygons not shown. For each polygon I know, which crop can be grown there, indicated by `True`, or not, indicated by `False`.  Moreover, I have the area and geometry information.
With this information, I now want to build land classes. Thus, I want to aggregate the data into different classes of arable land, by grouping polygons with identical crop cultivation potentials and order them by size. Therefore, I want to have the sum of the aggregated land class and the geometry information (this will be a MultiPolygon then, right?).

```
      land_class   wheat    rye         barley    ...   walnut   area   geometry
0     1            True     True        True            False    xxxxx  MULTIPOLYGON((...       
1     2            True     True        True            True     xxxxx  MULTIPOLYGON((...  
2     3            True     True        True            False    xxxxx  MULTIPOLYGON((...   
3     4            True     True        True            True     xxxxx  MULTIPOLYGON((...      
...........................................................................
???   ???          False    True        False           True     xx     MULTIPOLYGON((...
```

For example in the first land class could be an aggregation of all polygons that are `True` for all cereals (wheat, rye, barley, oat, etc.), most vegetables and fruits (not listed in the example table) and `False` for all nuts and seeds (walnut, etc.).

I can't see a way how to perform this aggregation in python or QGIS. Anyone has an advise for me?

Comment: In table two, that is all your classes? You want to specify each class manually or just create them out of all possible combinations?

Comment: No, that are not all my classes. I just wanted to use that as an example. I have way more crops than shown in the table, indicated by the dots. I'm sorry, if that was misleading and will edit the question. Thus, I will have more classes and combinations than shown, which should be created out of all possible combinations. Moreover, I would like to sum up the polygon area for the land classes and if that's possible have the geometry information of the land class in the geometry column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automatically assign class  by all combinations of True/False:

```
classes.txt:
wheat,rye,barley,walnut
True,True,True,False
True,True,True,True
True,True,True,False
True,True,True,True


import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/classes.txt', delimiter=',')
df['land_class'] = df.groupby(['wheat','rye','barley','walnut']).ngroup() #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50050617/assign-unique-numeric-group-ids-to-groups-in-pandas
```

Results:

```
df.sort_values(by='land_class')
Out: 
   wheat   rye  barley  walnut  land_class
0   True  True    True   False           0
2   True  True    True   False           0
1   True  True    True    True           1
3   True  True    True    True           1
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer.
After using  `.groupby()` and  `.sort_values()` I could use `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve` to combine the polygons of the different land classes, right?
Unfortunately, I have found  an error in my prior data processing, that I have to handle first.
I'll try it after fixing the problem and post the update.

Comment: You're proposed way works.
I used  `ngroup() ` for the aggregation,  ` dissolve()` to combine the polygons with identical crop cultivation potentials and  `sort_values ` to order the land classes by size.
 `gis_data_fr['land class'] = gis_data_fr.groupby(['wheat', 'rye', 'barley', 'oat', ...,'clover', 'faba_bean']).ngroup() `       
 `landclasses = gis_data_fr.dissolve(by='land class') `      
 `landclasses.sort_values(by=['area']) `
The only problem that I'm facing is that the area is not summed up. I tried 
 `landclasses = gis_data_fr.dissolve(by='land class', aggfunc='sum') `

Comment: But then the aggregation of the crops is different. I found a work-around by deleting the area and adding the area after the aggregation via the field calculator in QGIS.
Is there a way to achieve this with  `dissolve() `?

Comment: That works! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I used `ngroup()`  for the aggregation, `dissolve()` to combine the polygons with identical crop cultivation potentials. Then I calculated the area of the land classes and used `sort_values()` to order the land classes by descending size.

```
gis_data_fr['land class'] = gis_data_fr.groupby(['wheat', 'rye', 'barley', 'oat', ... ,'clover', 'faba_bean']).ngroup()
landclasses = gis_data_fr.dissolve(by='land class')
landclasses['area'] = landclasses.geometry.area
landclasses = landclasses.sort_values(by=['area'], ascending=False)
```